# NullPointerException sensorManager.getDefault…nsor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) must not be null IN Fragment android Koltin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sensors

I am using a compass in fragment and `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`, To Start sensor service I have to put

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

in `onViewcreated` when upload the app on the play store it shows an error most of the time

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
sensorManager.getDefault…nsor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) must not be null
```

`

help will be appreciated in advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but try:

```java
sensorManager = (SensorManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Comment: How do you retrieve your `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER `? Seems there is no such sensor on your device, so getting it returns null and you get this error.

Comment: That also might be true